# How to active mariadb log?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, linux

I want active log file in mariadb for check last query used in php, i find mysql config in internet like as blow:

```
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1

or

log = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

I added this config in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and `[mysql]` section and restart mariadb service.
but i didn't get any log, how to fix this?

i find answer:

```
[mysqld]
...
log_output = FILE
general_log = ON
general_log_file = mysql.log
```

mysql.log save in datadir, run `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE variable_name = 'datadir'` in mariadb to get datadir.

Comment: As this question shows up in search results here a reminder, you can use `SET global general_log = 1` to activate logging 'on the fly'   
**Whether or not** you should do this depends on your circumstances of course...

Answer (score 1):

You also need one of these:

```
log_output = FILE

log_output = TABLE
```

And put them in this section:

```
[mysqld]
```

('d' as in 'daemon' as in the 'server')

Comment: I added 3 lines:
`log_output = FILE` `general_log = ON` `general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Masoud92m - I added the other bug fix to my Answer.

Comment: I updated my question, please check it.

Comment: And you restarted the service?